# Create setup file with SQL Server database file (.mdf) in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, installation, installshield, local-database

I want to create an installation file, I created the program with the SQL Server database file and the entity data framework, located on the local database (`.mdf` file).

Well, after create an installation file with InstallShield, the program tells you that the SQL Server Express must be installed to read the database! Well, if I want to release this project, I can not tell everyone to install SQL Server Express!

How do other programs use the local database?

Comment: If you want to use the `.mdf` SQL Server database files, you ***MUST HAVE*** SQL Server installed - period. SQL Server Express is a **totally FREE** tool - anyone can download and install it free of charge, and use it for anything they like - and it can be added as a pre-requisite to your installation so that it will be downloaded and installed during installation process

Comment: you may think of changing Database you are using, try Access or SQLite DB.